# Intersection points of two circles.

Tags: circles

I understand that this is a common question and typically I can solve them, but this one keeps messing me up:

Find the points of intersection (A and B) on the circles $x^2+y^2+4x-10y+20=0$ and $x^2+y^2-4x-2y+12=0$; find the equation of the line $AB$.

Comment: There is something wrong with your second equation. The radius (squared) ends up being $-7$!

Comment: Please recheck the equations you entered. The intersection of the two functions you give is given by a line. Two circles cannot intersect in a straight line! They can intersect at no points, one point (tangent), 2 points (overlapping but not concurrent), or infinitely many points (if they represent the same circle.)

Comment: I was getting the same error until I looked over it again and I had missed something, I scrapped the page so I can't remember where though. Are you sure?

Comment: @John M No wonder it's messing you up.

Comment: @amWhy, the line I'm referring to is the line that could be drawn from point of intersection A to point of intersection B

Comment: I know that, @John. What I'm saying is that the two given "circles" intersect at infinitely many points, not just points A, B: and those points of intersection form a line. It is never possible that the points of intersection of two circles are all the points on some line. That is,  they share, or "overlap" along a common line, which is absurd. So I suspect at least the second circle was either mistyped, or is a misprint in the exercises you are working on.

Answer (score 1):

The two given equations, only the first of which is a circle, intersect at infinitely many points, not at just points $A, B$, and those points of intersection lie along a common line. It is never possible that the points of intersection of two *circles* are all the points on any one ***line.***

We can see this by solving for the points of intersection of the two equations: Since the left-hand sides of each equation is equal to zero, the left-hand sides are equal to one another. This gives us

$$\begin{align} x^2+y^2+4x-10y+20 & = x^2+y^2-4x-2y+12\\ \\  \iff 8x-8y+8& =0 \\ \\ \iff y& =x+1.\end{align}$$

So if there were a valid intersection, the "intersection" would consist of in this line. Can you see why this can not happen, given the first equation is the equation of a circle? If we had the equations of two circles, they would intersect at nowhere, or at one point (if they were tangent), or at 2 points (overlapping but not concurrent), or else at infinitely many points (if they represented the same circle.) None of those possibilities is met by these two equations. So they cannot define circles. The first does in fact define a circle (graph it to see). The second doesn't (no object has a radius of $\sqrt{-7}$, which occurs with the second equation if you complete the square to obtain the center and radius a circle would have, if it in were a circle.

So I suspect at least the second circle was either mistyped, or is a misprint in the exercises you are working on.

Comment: "Every point on the line $y=x+1$ solve both equations". This statement is false. For example, $x=0,y=1$ solves neither.

Comment: @yohBS Yes, of course, that mistake was careless of me.